# How to rewrite this Mathematica for loop code to be valid?

Tags: for-loop, foreach, wolfram-mathematica, graph-theory

I know that `Select[]` is some sort of Mathematica function that works with lists. However, I need to be able to grab each element by name into a variable so that I can use it just like in a `ForEach` loop.

Below, you can see that I converted one of my loops into a `Select`, but I have two more nested ones. Mathematica states that it has full procedural potential, but it does not have the `ForEach` loop, which makes it much more difficult to operate (do more than one function/action on) each element in some given loop.

Even if this could be converted into a functional list to be printed after, I'd rather have something that can print as it finds applicable graphs. Notice that I break functional purity in areas: random and printing and I would also like to even break out of the loop if an adjacent vertex is found that invalidates the tested one.

The algorithm that I want to do will loop through a large number of times (where it is not necessarily expected to stop before interesting results are reported) where the example has 5 currently. Produce a random graph and find out if it has a vertex with eccentricity 1 more than the radius while not being adjacent to one with eccentricity radius. If it has this property, it is printed.

```
For[x = 0, x < 5, x = x + 1,
 n = RandomInteger[{1, 10}];
 m = RandomInteger[{n - 1, n * (n - 1) / 2}];
 G = RandomGraph[{n, m}];
 R = Radius[G];
 V = VertexList[G];
 P = Select[V, R + 1 == VertexEccentricity[G, #]];
 ForEach [p, P,
  N = AdjacencyList[G, p];
  test = true;
  ForEach[n, N,
   If[VertexEccentricity[G, n] == R,
     test = false;
     ];
   ];
  If [test == true,
   Print[G]
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: When you need a loop, the `Do` form is typically cleaner. Especially in this case since you never use `x`, you will simply have `Do[code,{5}]`. As another side comment you should really avoid starting your own symbols with caps. ( `N` for example is a built in symbol )

Comment: Also, although as Bill shows you don't need it here, The `Do` construct can perform your  `ForEach` task, `Do[ code , {p,P}]` iterates over the list `P`

Answer (score 1):

This is functional code and I think displays what your example should

```
For[x = 0, x < 5, x = x + 1,
  n = RandomInteger[{1, 10}];
  m = RandomInteger[{n - 1, n*(n - 1)/2}];
  G = RandomGraph[{n, m}];
  R = GraphRadius[G];
  V = VertexList[G];
  P = Select[V, R+1 == VertexEccentricity[G, #]&];
  vertecc[CapN_] := If[And@@Map[VertexEccentricity[G, #] == R&, CapN], Print[G]];
  Map[vertecc[AdjacencyList[G, #]]&, P]
]
```

Radius was changed to GraphRadius when the Combinatorica package was incorporated into the kernel in around version 8 and you should use what is appropriate for your version.

Please test this carefully to make certain that there are no errors.